# Hibernate- Avoid many-to-many association- How to implement it right?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many, many-to-one

I'm a newbie to JPA and Hibernate.
I was able to set up some small basic examples as expected. 
Now I'm trying to use it for a first real world project. 
Studying the Hibernate best practices I found that you should avoid many-to-many relationships. I found relating questions here and I do understand the concept why not to use it but I'm not understanding how it should be implemented.

So when I have the often used example of a user that can the part of many groups and a group that does have many users, how to implement that.
So this is a many-to-many relationship. But I should not use many-to-many, as far as I understood because it is very likely that I will need other information in the future, like a specific role a user has in a group or a date when he joined.
So I use a two one-to-many relationships and a joining table which doesnt only contains the ids but also will contain additional information like role or date.
Is that right?
And then neither the 
class group has a property users 
nor 
the class users has a property groups
both have a property joinTableEntries?

Did I get the concept right so far?

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {



    private int userId;
    private String username;
    private Set<JTUserGroup> jtUserGroupSet=new HashSet<JTUserGroup>(0);


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "userid")
    public int getUserId()
    {
        return this.userId;
    }
    public void setUserId(int userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
    public Set<JTUserGroup> getJtUserGroupSet() {
        return jtUserGroupSet;
    }


    public void setJtUserGroupSet(Set<JTUserGroup> jtUserGroupSet) {
        this.jtUserGroupSet = jtUserGroupSet;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "forumgroup")
public class Group {

    private int groupId;
    private String groupname;
    private Set<JTUserGroup> jtUserGroupSet=new HashSet<JTUserGroup>(0);

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "groupid")
    public int getGroupId() {
        return groupId;
    }

    public void setGroupId(int groupId) {
        this.groupId = groupId;
    }

    public String getGroupname() {
        return groupname;
    }

    public void setGroupname(String groupname) {
        this.groupname = groupname;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "group")
    public Set<JTUserGroup> getJtUserGroupSet() {
        return jtUserGroupSet;
    }

    public void setJtUserGroupSet(Set<JTUserGroup> jtUserGroupSet) {
        this.jtUserGroupSet = jtUserGroupSet;
    }


}

@Entity
@Table(name = "jtusergroup")
public class JTUserGroup {
    private int joinId;
    private User user;
    private Group group;`enter code here`

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public int getJoinId() {
        return joinId;
    }

    public void setJoinId(int joinId) {
        this.joinId = joinId;
    }


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userid", nullable = false)
    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "groupid", nullable = false)
    public Group getGroup() {
        return group;
    }

    public void setGroup(Group group) {
        this.group = group;
    }

}
```

and then to use these I add a new user to a group like this:

```
User user1=new User();
        User user2=new User();
        User user3=new User();
        Group group1=new Group();
        Group group2=new Group();


        user1.setUsername("Mark");
        user2.setUsername("Anton");
        user3.setUsername("Maggy");
        group1.setGroupname("Mark_Maggy");
        group2.setGroupname("Maggy_Anton");

        JTUserGroup jt1=new JTUserGroup();
        jt1.setGroup(group1);
        jt1.setUser(user1);


        JTUserGroup jt2=new JTUserGroup();
        jt2.setGroup(group1);
        jt2.setUser(user3);


        JTUserGroup jt3=new JTUserGroup();
        jt3.setGroup(group2);
        jt3.setUser(user3);


        JTUserGroup jt4=new JTUserGroup();
        jt4.setGroup(group2);
        jt4.setUser(user2);


        GenericDAO<JTUserGroup> jtDao=new GenericDAO<JTUserGroup>();

        jtDao.beginTransaction();
        jtDao.insert(jt1);
        jtDao.insert(jt2);
        jtDao.insert(jt3);
        jtDao.insert(jt4);
        jtDao.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just image this, you have `User` and let's say that  `Group` is extending your user. Now your 'Group' has a sub-class which is `JTUserGroup`. Let's say that `User` has one-to-many relationship with `Group` (based on your logic, user can belong on many groups). Now the question, how can `User` know about `JTUserGroup`? You need somehow to get FK(as everybody knows that FK creates assosiations with classes) in your `User` class to know about all your 'Group' sub-classes and rely on logic, belong (let's say) for a several sub-classes which belongs to '`Group`'. It is not impossible to do it or you need to make complex solutions to implement it, and what about SQL queries - it will look very complex. So you need to handle it somehow - the solution is `inheritance`. Doing this you can create associations between classes in very easy way. If you will not have many info (or let's say complex tables schema with a lot of info) you can use `SINGLE_TABLE` strategy. If there will be a lot of info/columns(in your tables), your data will not be normalized with this strategy so better use `JOINED` or `TABLE_PER_CONCRETE_CLASS` strategy.